# Litecoin mining hardware

Tags: litecoin, mining-hardware, hashpower, scrypt

Does readily available hardware exist which is capable of at least 25MH/s for litecoin mining?

So basically, I am after hardware which can mine scrypt type coins which can do at least 25MH/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quite detailed Litecoin mining performance collection for different hardwares.

https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison

Comment: Based on this link it seems the best amd gc can only manage about 1.5mh/s ???

Answer (score 0):

You could put 6 of them in 1 machine.... Totalling about 9Mhz ... So you would need 3 of such machines. Warning though, putting more than 2 amd 7990 cards in a machine will give you heat dissipation problems

Answer (score 0):

The list that Tibor identified is old school, contrast it this emerging [FPGA/ASIC](https://litecointalk.org/index.php?topic=6506.0) list for Litecoin.